# Only RDP works from local lan to azure across Site 2 Site IPSEC

Tags: azure, vpn

We have a site to site IPSEC VPN between our local lan and azure.
From the azure platform we can do everything we want.
From the local lan we are restricted to RDP only.
No matter what I do I cant get other services working from local to azure.
Please help.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check.

1. Windows firewall on the server VM
2. Any Network Security Groups

If you can do "everything" from the Azure platform then it could be an NSG or an outbound rule in your firewall.

Are you RDP-ing to the private IP or the public IP of the VM? If it's public IP then it is most probably going over the Internet and not the IPSec tunnel.